# VS code markdown text wrapping issue

Tags: visual-studio-code, archlinux, xorg

I am using using visual studio code on arch linux, with official compiled version download from arch linux aur source (https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/visual-studio-code-bin). However, I found that the text wrapping in markdown mode does not work well.

The under screenshot was taken from my linux desktop computer.
[Linux Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBhmh.png)

As we can see that, in the last 2 line, part of words are hidden due to incorrect word wrapping.

This screenshot is taken from my windows desktop, which is what I want to have on linux desktop.
[Windows Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNvNN.png)

Background information related to my Linux desktop:

System: Archlinux

System version: all of software are updated to latest version

VS Code Version: 1.75.1-1

Windows Manager: awesome wm(with Xorg)

What I have tried:

1. reinstall vs code, and removing all of add-on/extensions installed, does't work.
2. try to use code-oss, which is compiled by arch linux community, does't work.
3. clean all of user settings, does't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue. This is due to the settings in my .xinitrc to start X environment for awesome WM. I put a line "export LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8" into .xinitrc. If I remove it from .xinitrc, then the 'bug' is fixed. I still don't know the reason of it.
If there are any thoughts, please free to share with us.
Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).